# Xcode 13 Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap not found for a brand new project just initialized

Tags: xcode, react-native

A brand new React Native 0.66 app was created with command below:

```
  npx react-native init myapp
```

The app was launched successfully with `npx react-native run-ios`. In Xcode 13, the `myapp.xcodeproj` is opened to test if the build will pass. To my surprise, build throws the error below:

```
fatal error: module map file '/Users/macair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xyz_app6-gpxsmunajzbqoualaavtsfpnerep/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found
```

What is wrong here? I haven't put any code into the app and it is all React Native generated code. Xcode becomes beast by itself even though the React Native app itself runs fine. That's why the app has to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common problem. The solution works here is just open the myapp.xcworkspace in Xcode instead of myapp.xcodeproj. The build upon workspace went through without any error.